# replace a tuple inside of a list by it's first entry

Tags: python, list, replace, tuples, equals

I'm using python 3

I have a list of different tuples. the first value of every tuple is always the same but the rest vary. How can I search through the list after the tuple containing the first value and then replacing the entire tuple whit an new one inside the list?
ex:
this is my tuple: `(122, 23, 24, 9)`

this tuples are inside the list, the first value is always the same but the rest vary
how can i find the tuple inside of the list that got a first value equal to mine tuple "122" and replace it whit my whole tuple

```
(125, 34, 35, 21)

(122, 341, 5, 27)

(124, 31, 51, 7)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you please post and example of the input you want to process, and what the desired output would be?

Comment: as i told, i got a list that contains some tuples, i need to replace one of the tuples in the list whit a new one, the tuple that i need to replace is the one that got the first valu equal to the tuple i want to replace it whit.( the first value inside of the tuples is tup[0])

Answer (score 8):

```
l = [(125, 34, 35, 21), (122, 341, 5, 27), (124, 31, 51, 7)]
t = (122, 23, 24, 9)

out = [t if e[0] == t[0] else e for e in l]
print(out)
```

This prints out:

```
[(125, 34, 35, 21), (122, 23, 24, 9), (124, 31, 51, 7)]
```

Comment: +1 Much prettier, I forgot about `else` in list comprehension!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list is `l` and your tuple is `t` and you always have just one tuple to replace:

```
l[l.index([_ for _ in l if _[0] == t[0]][0])] = t
```

Not pretty, I admit.

If there are multiple tuples in your list that have matching first value, only the first will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [(125, 34, 35, 21), (122, 341, 5, 27), (124, 31, 51, 7)]
t = (122, 23, 24, 9)
for i, v in enumerate(a):
    if v[0] == t[0]:
        a[i] = t
        break
```

However, there are different meanings about changing the value of a list that you are iterating over, but because you break right after i think there is no problem! Note that the break means you only look for one possible tuple in the list, also if you're list contains millions of entries, you do not loop through all values if you're value is located early in the list, for better performance.

Edit:

Added the replace tuple `t`

Answer (score 0):

You can search for elements in a list by using the `index` method or by looping over the list. E.g for the `index` method:

```
mylist = [(125, 34, 35, 21),
          (122, 341, 5, 27),
          (124, 31, 51, 7)]

idx = mylist.index((122, 341, 5, 27))
# idx should be '1'
```

The problem is, that it only finds entries if the whole tuple is exactly found. So this might not be the best solution for you.

With a loop this might look like this:

```
for idx, itm in enumerate(mylist):
    if itm[0] == 122:
        mylist[idx] = (1,2,3,4,5) # your new tuple
```

I'm using `enumerate` to add the index for each element in the list.